# Using two loops to loop two variables for generating excel file with different data and sheet names in R

Tags: r, excel, for-loop

I have written a function that creates excel files based on different taxa. Each taxa has to form it's own sheet with its name i.e. "Phyla" sheet from `Phylum_count_1.1` data.

```
excel_taxa <- function(taxa_var, taxa, file_name) {
  if (file.exists(file_name)) {
    file.remove(file_name)
    write.xlsx(taxa_var, file_name, sheetName = taxa, row.names = FALSE) 
    if(file.exists(file_name)) {
      write.xlsx(taxa_var, file_name, sheetName = taxa, append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  } else {
    write.xlsx(taxa_var, file_name, sheetName = taxa, row.names = FALSE) 
    if(file.exists(file_name)) {
      write.xlsx(taxa_var, file_name, sheetName = taxa, append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  }
}
```

The function works fine, however I have a problem when I am trying to add the data with its associated taxa name. So `Domain_count1.1` should have a sheet name "Domain". Here is my attempt to conduct the for loops:

```
var_list1 = list(Domain_count_1.1, Phylum_count_1.1)
var_list2 = list("Domain", "Phyla")

for (i in var_list1) {
  for (j in var_list2) {
    excel_taxa(i, j, "test.xlsx")
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following loop to create my excel files. it may help you

```r
library(xlsx)

file_name = "test.xlsx"

#data
Domain_count_1.1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:100, nrow = 10))
Phylum_count_1.1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(101:200, nrow = 10))

#lists
taxa_var = list(Domain_count_1.1, Phylum_count_1.1)
taxa = list("Domain", "Phyla")

#creat a workbook  an if the file exist delet it
if (file.exists(file_name)) {
  file.remove(file_name)
}

wb <- createWorkbook(type = "xlsx")

#loop

for (i in 1:length(taxa_var)) {
  sheet <- createSheet(wb, taxa[[i]])
  addDataFrame(
    taxa_var[[i]],
    sheet,
    startRow = 3,
    startColumn = 1,
    col.names = TRUE,
    row.names = T
  )
  saveWorkbook(wb, paste0(file_name))

}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great! I just get a message when I open my excel sheet that tells me the file was repaired. I've got some NA values, could that be the problem?

Comment: I also get the error for the first time, but the content is okay.